# Android Compose LazyColum Rendering Issue when changing list sorting

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is how it looks when I hardcode the text inside the cards:

[image: working]

This is how it looks when I use my data from the viewModel, but it **only has this issue after changing the sorting method** of the list and it only happens in the middle of the list:

[image: not working]

Here is the Code of the two Composables:

```
@Composable
fun BookShelfList(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: BookShelfViewModel,
    toolbarHeight: Dp
) {
    val bookList by remember { viewModel.books }

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 16.dp,
            top = toolbarHeight + 16.dp,
            end = 16.dp,
            bottom = 16.dp
        ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        var items = bookList
        if (viewModel.sortingMethod.value == "A-Z")
            items = bookList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.title })
        items(items) { book ->
            BookShelfListItem(navController, book)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BookShelfListItem(navController: NavController, book: Book) {
    Card(
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { navController.navigate("second_screen") }
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(120.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.width(90.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.book_cover_placeholder),
                contentDescription = "Book cover",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = book.title,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you remove sorting then everything is fine?

Comment: Yes it renders correctly before changing the sorting method in the UI. 
It also works correctly if i use hardcoded text, then it doesn't matter what sorting method i use it always works.

Comment: you can try to put sorting logic outside of `LazyColumn`

Comment: I tried putting it above LazyColumn, didn't fix the issue

Comment: The problem is that you are sorting it inside Composable which can be recomposed multiple times. I would sort it outside of `BookShelfList` and just pass `bookList` into this. No need to sort inside this component

Comment: Should I sort it in the viewModel?

Comment: Ideally yes and just pass the sorted list into that component

Comment: I will move this to the viewModel since it shouldn't sort the list every time the composable gets recomposed but i found out that the problem disappeared after upgrading to compose version from 1.0.0-beta07 to 1.0.0-beta08 which just released yesterday